# Android Textbox using HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to create the layout of this textbox:

[image]

The one for email (or where he's writing his phone number) using `HTML5` and `CSS3`.

The problem is the requirements for this textbox:

- it has to be responsive (width: 100%)
- I don't want anything on hover (no need for the bottom border to become blue)
- I don't want to use JavaScript

Any suggestions? I tried several ways but I'm always having problem.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. You can use www.jsfiddle.com to post examples if it's too much code to add to your question.

Comment: The text-input (no such element as a 'textbox') *doesn't* have a `width: 100%` (the heading/`label`) does. Which one are you looking at? Show what you've tried, explain the 'few problems' so we're not repeating your mistakes, or so we can solve the problems.

Comment: Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/BPCUs/

Comment: The text-input, I want to do it with a `width: 100%` I don't want the label

Comment: And what're the problems with what you've got?

Comment: The problem with this, is that I can't add a padding-left for the input in order to push the placeholder (and text) to the left.

Comment: That's it David, thanks! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having is that an element's width is composed of the defined `width` *plus* the `padding` (of both sides) *and* the `border-width` (of both sides).

To work around this, in compliant browsers, use the `box-sizing` property set to `border-box` (which includes the `padding` and `border-width` *inside* the defined width), therefore:

```
.textbox{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(160,160,160);
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    /*padding-left: 5px;*/
    float: left;
}
```

Needs to have the following added:

```
.textbox {
    /* the above not changed, the following added */
    padding-left: 2em; /* an arbitrary dimension to demonstrate, adjust to taste */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BPCUs/1/).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).